# allowing special characters in a url

Tags: php

I've created a CMS where it creates a page based on the title of the page the client gives.

E.g. 'About Us' get created as 'about-us.php'

It currently uses the following to strip out all characters that aren't allowed, I've added in the code for when you go to edit the page and call it something else so it renames the file.

```
    function toAscii($str) {        
        $clean = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_|+ -]/", '', $str);
        $clean = strtolower(trim($clean, '-'));
        $clean = preg_replace("/[\/_|+ -]+/", '-', $clean);
        return $clean;
    }
// Renames the file
    rename(toAscii($row_Recordset1['content_title']).".php", toAscii($_POST['content_title']).".php");
```

But I really want to allow these special characters so i modified the above function to do the following:

```
    function toAscii($str) {
        $clean = strtolower($str);
        $clean = str_replace(";", "%3B", $clean);
        $clean = str_replace("/;", "%2F", $clean);
        $clean = str_replace("?", "%3F", $clean);
        $clean = str_replace(":", "%3A", $clean);
        $clean = str_replace("&", "%26", $clean);
        $clean = str_replace("@", "%40", $clean);
        $clean = str_replace("=", "%3D", $clean);   
        $clean = str_replace(" ", "-", $clean);
        return $clean;
    }
// Renames the file
rename(toAscii($row_Recordset1['content_title']).".php", toAscii($_POST['content_title']).".php");
```

I know it's not elegant but it should work in theory.

It doesn't.

So when a filename should be 'shows-%2F-exhibitions.php' it actually comes up as 'shows-/-exhibitions.php' which is obviously disallowed.

How can I force it to keep in the hex code in the filename rather than applying the hex code and ending up with a forward slash again?

Or are you just not allowed forward slashes in any shape or form in a URL?

Comment: You can get around the issue by escaping `%` as well. Wouldn't it be better to altogether disallow those extra characters though?

Comment: % is a reserved character and can't be used in a filename http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved_characters_and_words

Answer (score 0):

take a look at urlencode function (and corresponding urldecode)

btw you've got a typo in line with `str_replace('/;' ...` (there's redundant semicolon after forward slash)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: It's ok, I know about the semi-colon.

Answer (score 0):

Universal version of your toAscii function:

```php
function toAscii($str) {
    return iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $src);
}
```

It is very common to strip non-ascii characters away from URL, so it is much easier to read and write these URLs. You can also include some unique ID in URL to be sure that it is unique and keep additional text for better readibility of links. Example: http://example.com/123-some-article. To process this url, simply cut number away and search database for it, then compare rest of the text to prevent of creating google bombs.

If you really need special characters in URL, you need to encode them differently than url_encode does, becouse that % encoding is decoded by server before your PHP script gets it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to completely disallow any characters other than `a-zA-Z0-9_` in your filenames. Use a database table to map the nice human-readable names to the filenames. Make sure you handle "identical" names as well, e.g.:

```
Shows/Events --> showsevents.php
Shows-Events --> showsevents1.php
```